# Simplification of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^{n}+2^{n}}{3^{n}\cdot 2^{n}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm looking at

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^{n}+2^{n}}{3^{n}\cdot 2^{n}}}$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{(\dfrac{2}{3})^{n}+1}$

How does one derive this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: forget limit for the moment... a direct computation gives

$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n+2^n}{3^n2^n}}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1+(\frac{2}{3})^n}{2^n}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[n]{1+(\frac{2}{3})^n}
$$
now, for $n\ge 1$ we have $(\frac{2}{3})^{n+1}=\frac{2}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{n}\le(\frac{2}{3})^{n}\le\dots\le\frac{2}{3}$, hence:
$$
1\le1+(\frac{2}{3})^n\le 1+\frac{2}{3}=\frac{5}{3}
$$
therefore, like the *square root* function is increasing (it preserve inequalities order):
$$
1 \le \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{1+(\frac{2}{3})^n} \le \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{5}{3}} = 1
$$
The limit is $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Your question:

$f(n): = (1/2)\sqrt[n]{1+(2/3)^n}.$

$(1/2) \sqrt[n]{1+0} \lt f(n) \lt$

$ (1/2)\sqrt[n]{1+1}$, i.e.

$1/2 \lt f(n) \lt (1/2) \sqrt[n]{2}$.

Squeeze:

$1/2 \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) \le$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  (1/2)\sqrt[n]{2}$;

$1/2 \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) \le 1/2.$

Used: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{2} =1.$